# Как с помощью CSS сделать сглаживание шрифта?

Tags: css

Вытащил с ютуба шрифт Roboto, но он отображается по-другому.
Как сделать сглаживание шрифта?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Из ютуба бесплатный шрифт? Похоже, что-то перемудрили. Бегом на гугл-фонтс https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
* {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello. This is Roboto font</p>
```